# Upgraded to iOS 7.1 , iAd now broken

Tags: ios7, iad, ios7.1

Just updated to 7.1 and now my app with iad does not work. Does not display any ads at all. Is there a reason that iad on my app running 7.0.6 works great, but on 7.1 absolutely zero ads are showing up. Just wondering if apple made any changes to this. Thanks for any insight.

Comment: iAds are broken on my app as well. Console log shows the following:
backboardd[28] <Error>: HID: The 'Passive' connection 'AdSheet' access to protected services is denied.

Comment: I found this on the developer forums.  https://devforums.apple.com/message/949987#949987  
(This is normal for new iOS releases.) I will keep an eye on this and keep ya posted.

Comment: I get the same error trying to use iBeacons. I don't know if this is in any way related.

Comment: Update: Still not working.

Comment: Well I solved my issue. I had the CLLocationManager as a local variable in the controller's viewDidLoad. After makeing it a property everything worked well. I don't know anything about iAds, just found this question after googling the log entry in the first comment. Maybe my solution works for you too.